# Dojo DataGrid Virtual Scrolling How-To?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, dojo, grid

I've been digging around for this one quite a bit.  I'm using dojox.grid.datagrid and I have an ajax call that brings back 200-300 rows.

The grid renders and scrolls just fine in Chrome but scrolling is excruciatingly slow in IE 7 and 8.  I'd like to use virtual scrolling to try and remedy the issue but can't find any sample code.

Here's what my code looks like at present.

```
function setupAvailableScenes(location) {
var avaiableScenesGridPane = dijit.byId("AvaiableScenesGridPane");
var availableScenesGrid = dijit.byId("AvailableScenesGrid");
if (_isFirstLoad) {

    availableScenesGrid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
        id: 'AvailableScenesGrid',
        store: availableScenesStore,
        query: { Id: "*" },
        sortInfo: "1",
        rowsPerPage: 20,
        autoHeight:20,
        style: "width:315px",
        structure: [
                { name: "Available Scenes", field: "Name", width: "85%" },
                {   name: " ",
                    field: "_item",
                    rowsPerPage: "25",
                    type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
                    editable: false,
                    width: "15%",
                    formatter: function (scene) {
                        return new dijit.form.Button(
                        {
                            label: "+",
                            onClick: function () {
                                AddSceneToSelectedScenes(scene);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            ]
    });

    avaiableScenesGridPane.set('content', availableScenesGrid);
}

var availableScenesStore = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({
    url: _applicationPath + "/Location/" + location.Id + "/Scene.json",
    preventUrlCache: true
});

availableScenesGrid.setStore(availableScenesStore);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you specified rowsPerPage=25, it is already doing virtual scrolling (it pulls the new set of rows only when user scrolls down)

Since you mention scrolling is very slow, the performance issue seems to be around rendering the new rows - you may try a couple things to improve performance:
1) remove autoHeight attribute. Instead, specify a fixed height in the style attribute
2) in the formatter function, instead of returning a dijit, try returning a simple html button/anchor styled as button
so remove the type:dojox.grid.cells._Widget attribute and in the format function return the html you want to use

Comment: thanks for taking a look.  I know it's supposed to do virtual scrolling, but i don't see the parameters being sent in the headers.

I'm assuming the startrow and number of rows to return would be parameters I would have to send to my controller and then handle in my data layer to return the number of rows.

I'll see if a simple button will do in the dijit.   Let me know what you think about the virtual scrolling though.

Comment: hmm - could you please clarify? which headers do you expect the parmeters to be sent? are you referring to lazy loading or virtual scrolling?

Comment: Virtual scrolling.  Basically, i want the grid to load up 25-50 rows at a time.

Comment: so it should do that already. Can you try putting a console.log statement in your format function. As you scroll down beyond 25 rows, you should see a new set of console.log statements confirming that virtual scrolling is working.

Comment: ok i read your comment again and what you are referring to is actually lazy loading (since you want it to goto the server to load new set of rows) QRS is what you want as @ryan-corradini mentioned. However, be careful though since going to the server to fetch a new batch might slow down your scrolling even more. i suggest using QRS with appropriate rowsPerPage setting based on your usecase

Comment: thanks vijay.  I'm going to give your suggestion a whirl in the morning and will accept your answer then.  Much appreciated.

Comment: ok, tried jsut wiring up a button, but i need to pass the entire object though and I can't do that with something like: var returnButton = "<button onClick = \"AddSceneToSelectedScenes('" + scene.Id[0] + "')\">+</button>"; i'll have to do some js to get that.  Either way, i'm going to accept the anser since the rendering of the rows is clearly the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Often one of the biggest things you can do to improve DataGrid performance is to throw away the ItemFileReadStore/WriteStore and use an optimized data store (personally I like QueryReadStore). It would mean needing a server-side servlet of some kind (PHP/JSP/etc) to handle the virtual scrolling/pagination, but I've seen major perf boosts over just using a store backed by a JSON file.

Some other things to consider, which may or may not help:

- give your anonymous formatter function a name and try scrolling the table with the Chrome or Firebug profiles turned on to see if it's hogging a lot of cycles (or, like Vijay Agrawal said, you could try replacing the dijit.form.Button with a vanilla html `<button>` tag)
- you shouldn't actually need to specify the `dojox.grid.cells._Widget` type for that cell; having a custom formatter returning a valid Dijit should be sufficient to make the Grid do the right thing.

Comment: Ryan,  many thanks for getting back to me on google+ and for writing a response here.  I'd like to use a read store but I need to update the grid on the fly so I think i need to stick the write store (correct me if i'm wrong).

I looked through the sample code you posted on your site and I will keep it in mind in the future.

i wonder, if i used a JsonStore if the grid will remain editable.  I.e. Can i edit the grid then post back through an ajax call.  Or do I need a write store to edit the grid at all.  I think I do, but I'd like to be wrong ;)

Comment: A JsonRest store should allow you to persist your changes. There's a tutorial on the Dojo website that touches on how to do this: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/store_driven_grid/